# How to make reversed phylogenetic tree in d3.js?

Tags: d3.js

I'm making a reversed tree based on the example in the [d3.js documentation](https://observablehq.com/@d3/tree-of-life?intent=fork). And I need to somehow turn this tree inside out like in the picture. But I don't know how to do it, maybe there is some option in hierarchy that changes the order of data or it can be done in some other way?

Thanks in advance for your help

Result I want to achieve:
[image: result I want to achieve]